# BigQuery: Arrange columns from 2 table to get a single table but only get unique rows from table2

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables and in the output, I want a single table with rows from both the tables one below the other.

- **Requirement is**: Get all the rows from `table1` but exclude rows from `table2` with condition that **`email` or `productname` is not present in `table1`**.

Refer image. Yellow cells in `table2` should not be present in the output, since they are present in `table1`, as highlighted. So only sr.no. 2,4,5,7 from table-2 should be present in output table.

[image: Example input and desired output]

Can someone suggest solution?

The logic I tried is `UNION` to first get all rows one below the other. However I'm not getting logic to exclude matching rows from `table2` after `UNION`. I tried multiple options as commented below in my code:

```sql
  with a AS (
  SELECT
    email AS leademail,
    website AS leadwebsite,
    productname AS leadproductname,
    source AS leadsource,
    detail AS leaddetail,
    leaddate
  FROM
    `table1`),
  b AS (
  SELECT
    email AS contactemail,
    website AS contactwebsite,
    productname AS contactproductname,
    source AS contactsource,
    detail AS contactdetail,
    contactdate
  FROM
    `table2`)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  a union all
SELECT
  *
FROM
  b
  --option1 except distinct select * from b
  --option2 union all select * from b
  --option3 except distinct select * from b
  --option4 left join
  --(select * from b where contactemail not in (select leademail from a))
ON
  leademail=contactemail
  AND leadproductname=contactproductname
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to perform this query by using the `UNION ALL` operator to append filtered rows from the `table2` to the `table1` and I used the operator `NOT IN` to filter the rows from `table2`.

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table1
UNION ALL (
  SELECT table2.*
  FROM
    table2
  WHERE
    table2.email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM table1)
    OR table2.productname NOT IN (SELECT productname FROM table1)
)
```

Also, I made the following executable query based on your example data so more people can play with:

```sql
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT
    "abc@abc.com" AS email,
    "abc.com" AS website,
    "msoffice" AS productname,
    "abc" AS source,
    "one" AS detail,
    "12-Dec-19" AS leaddat
  UNION ALL SELECT "pqr1@pqr1.com","pqr1.com","chrome","pqr1","two","12-Dec-19"
  UNION ALL SELECT "xyz@xyz.com","xyz.com","iphone","xyz",NULL,"12-Dec-19"
  UNION ALL SELECT "zzz@zzz.com","zzz.com","macbook","zzz","three","12-Dec-19"
  UNION ALL SELECT "xyz1@xyz.com","xyz1.com","itunes","xyz1",NULL,"12-Jan-20"
  UNION ALL SELECT "google@google.com",NULL,"googlecloud","xyz2",NULL,"12-Jan-20"
  UNION ALL SELECT "123@123.com","123.com","yahoomail","123","xyz","12-Jan-20"
), table2 as (
  SELECT
    NULL AS email,
    "abc.com" AS website,
    "msoffice" AS productname,
    "abc" AS source,
    "one" AS detail,
    "11-Nov-19" AS leaddat
  UNION ALL SELECT "pqr@pqr.com","pqr.com","playstore","pqr1","two","12-Jan-20"
  UNION ALL SELECT "123@123.com","123.com",NULL,"123","xyz","12-Oct-19"
  UNION ALL SELECT "abc1@abc1.com","abc1.com",NULL,"xyz",NULL,"12-Jan-20"
  UNION ALL SELECT "itunes@apple.com",NULL,"ipod","zzz","three","12-Jan-20"
  UNION ALL SELECT NULL,NULL,"googlecloud","xyz2",NULL,"12-Jan-20"
  UNION ALL SELECT "yahoo@yahoo.com",NULL,"yahoomail",NULL,NULL,"12-Jan-20"
)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  table1
UNION ALL (
  SELECT table2.*
  FROM
    table2
  WHERE
    table2.email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM table1)
    OR table2.productname NOT IN (SELECT productname FROM table1)
)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @PolOrtiz. Your solution worked. Appreciate your response.